# How can a server accurately determine what HTTP client i'm using?

Tags: rest, http, ssl, web-scraping, networking

Just to make this clear, this is not a header/IP issue. I'm scraping a site and the sysadmins are somehow able to accurately determine what http client/library I'm using and subsequently blocking those requests based on the client alone. I downgraded said http client to an older version and I was successfully able to reach the endpoint again, but they caught on shortly after and blocked that one too. What methods are they utilizing to determine this? What other identifiers are being sent for them to be able to pinpoint what http library/client I'm using?

Other http clients work fine after being blocked, even when sending the exact same headers on the same IP.

Comment: You are running against some bot protection. Methods used by these are usually not openly documented and might change without notice. Common methods involve analyzing HTTP headers, fingerprinting the TLS stack, behavior of how resources gets accessed (like loading HTML but not the images inside), timing behavior which distinguish human from bot ... It is impossible to say what is used in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like modifying TLS Elliptic Curve identifiers bypassed their check.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).